# Interesting behavior using casting of structures

Tags: c++, c

I have an interesting behavior of my program. Its better to show code first.

```
typedef struct PS {
    int num;
} PR;

typedef struct PS* PN;

typedef struct {
    int num;
    int tmp;
} VD;

void F (PN VPtr)
{
    register VD* qVPtr = (VD*)VPtr;
    // if this is call #2
    // qVPtr->tmp already is 8 for VP arg
    // qVPtr->tmp already is 16 for VP1 arg

    switch(VPtr->num){
    case 0:
        qVPtr->tmp = 8;
    return;
    case 1:
        qVPtr->tmp = 16;
        return;
    }
}

int main()
{
    PN VP = NULL;
    VP = (PN)malloc(sizeof(PR));

    VP->num = 0;
    F (VP);

    PN VP1 = NULL;
    VP1 = (PN)malloc(sizeof(PR));

    VP1->num = 1;
    F (VP1);

    F (VP);     // call #2 with VP arg
    F (VP1);    // call #2 with VP1 arg

    return 0;
}
```

In main function `VP` and `VP1` does not knows about `qVPtr` and `tmp` field, but depending on `VPtr` argument in `F` function it is possible to obtain last value of `qVPtr->tmp`.

Can you explain in detail about this possibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing strange in F behaviour - if you told it to consider pointer 
VPtr as pointer to VD struct, it considers memory, starting with VPtr as memory containing VD struct object though there is no any VD object there. Your "magic" appears because both structs PR and VD start with integer field of the same size.
But next part of memory is unallocated that means system can do whatever it wants with it and when you write there you can shoot in your leg.

Answer (score 3):

In the function `F` you write into unallocated memory, which is undefined behavior. Bad and weird things *will* happen.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply writing past the end of the allocated memory block. It is small enough so the chance that it would hit unallocated virtual memory region is low, hence you are not being greeted with a segmentation fault. But run the program in a memory checker like `valgrind` and enjoy the output:

```
==624== Invalid write of size 4
==624==    at 0x4004E2: F (pr.c:23)
==624==    by 0x400529: main (pr.c:37)
==624==  Address 0x4c38044 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==624==    at 0x4A05FDE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==624==    by 0x40050F: main (pr.c:34)
==624==
==624== Invalid write of size 4
==624==    at 0x4004EB: F (pr.c:26)
==624==    by 0x400555: main (pr.c:43)
==624==  Address 0x4c38094 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==624==    at 0x4A05FDE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==624==    by 0x40053B: main (pr.c:40)
==624==
==624== Invalid write of size 4
==624==    at 0x4004E2: F (pr.c:23)
==624==    by 0x400561: main (pr.c:45)
==624==  Address 0x4c38044 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==624==    at 0x4A05FDE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==624==    by 0x40050F: main (pr.c:34)
==624==
==624== Invalid write of size 4
==624==    at 0x4004EB: F (pr.c:26)
==624==    by 0x40056D: main (pr.c:46)
==624==  Address 0x4c38094 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==624==    at 0x4A05FDE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==624==    by 0x40053B: main (pr.c:40)
```